# shell_exec doesn't work with find

Tags: php, linux, shell-exec

I'm trying to implement php script on server created by someone else.
I try `echo shell_exec('ls');` and it works.

```
var_dump(shell_exec('find / -name "tmp.txt"'));
```

returns null.
However when I try it in ssh console, the output is correct. What can cause it? What can I check

Comment: What web server are you using? Apache?

Comment: Yes, I'm using web server Apache

Comment: Do you get any result when you try var_dump(shell_exec('find . -name *.php'))? Make sure "find" is usable by the php user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to locate something in the root directory, which your web server doesn't have permissions to access (by design) - what you're wanting to do would be a security concern, so my suggestion is to place your work in a folder inside your website, owned by the same user that is allowed to access files on your drive, typically `www-data`.

Perhaps you don't want to read the root directory of the server itself, and you just want to read a file in the same directory as the website. Switching out the `/` for a `.` will access the current directory, not the base directory:

```
var_dump(shell_exec('find . -name "tmp.txt"'));
```

Or, you could try an absolute path:

```
var_dump(shell_exec('find /path/to/files -name "tmp.txt"'));
```

This is uncommon, but you may need to point to an absolute path for `find` as well. You can test if you need to do this by running `var_dump(shell_exec('find .'));` and if it has no output then you will probably have to. Use `/usr/bin/find` instead if this is the case.

**[Read more about how to set permissions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/proper-permissions-for-web-server-s-directory)**
**[Apache: File and Directory Ownership and Permissions for Web Content](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/FileSystemPermissions)**

Comment: Additional problems you might run into: 1) find may not be accessible by php your script 2) recursive searching from root folder "/" may take longer than your max script execution time

Comment: @SergeyScopin let us know if you need any more help :-)

Comment: Actually, I've just changed root (/) to certain directory and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

A reason for this can be a missing PATH environment variable.

Please check `getenv('PATH')` and try to use the absolute path to find. A usual place is /usr/bin/find or /bin/find.

```
var_dump(shell_exec('/usr/bin/find / -name "tmp.txt"'));
```